# How to round image border in generated pdf

Tags: php, css, pdf

I should round the image in pdf. I generate a pdf with PHP that shows also an image inside. Everything works correctly. When I add "width" and "hight" to the image it works, but when I try to round the corners of the image it does not work. When I envelop image with div and add to div border-radius and overflow: hidden; ->  overflow: hidden; does not work.
Here is part of my code:

```
<style>
  .visuel-carte{
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: 25px; 
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .visuel-carte img {
     height: 270px;
     width: 420px;
     border-radius: 20px
  }
</style>
<page>
 <div class="visuel-carte">
   <img src="<?php echo $eboutique['visuel_carte']; ?>"/>
 </div>
</page>
```

maybe you have some idea?

I tried also

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $eboutique['visuel_carte'];?>')">
```

but it shows me an error

Answer (score 0):

I found an error in my code:
does not work:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $eboutique['visuel_carte'];?>')">
```

work (without a little quotes ;) ):

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $eboutique['visuel_carte'];?>)">
```